# JavaScript and jQuery check for image file and assign CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, beginner

This is my first attempt at JavaScript, so I am looking to learn.

I have a website that has jQuery built in and I wanted to leverage that in the following way:

1. I want to get a number variable that precedes a certain text string (`*n*/portal.css`)
2. Get the name of the current webpage
3. Use this number and pageName to help build a URL to a specifically named image file  The image will have the same name as the webpage with an "_hd.jpg" appended to it
4. Check if the image file exists and if it does add this image to a CSS div background otherwise do nothing

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        $(document).foundation();
        //get webpage name
        var loc = window.location.href
        var fileNameIndex = loc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        var dotIndex = loc.lastIndexOf('.');
        var pageName = loc.substring(fileNameIndex, dotIndex < fileNameIndex ? loc.length : dotIndex);

        //get number variable
        var head = document.head
        var portalCss = head.innerHTML.match(/\/[0-9]+\/portal.css/);

        var portalNum = portalCss[0].replace("/", "")
        portalNum = portalNum.replace("portal.css", "")

        //build url for image
        var HeaderImgUrl = '/Portals/' + portalNum + '/Images/' + pageName + '_hd.jpg'

        //check if image exists and assign css values to css class RowPageHeader
        $.ajax({
            url: HeaderImgUrl, //or your url
            success: function (data) {
                $(".RowPageHeader").css("background-image", "url(" + HeaderImgUrl + ")");
                $(".RowPageHeader").css("background-position", "center top");
                $(".RowPageHeader").css("background-size", "100% auto");
                $(".RowPageHeader").css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
                $(".RowPageHeader").css("overflow", "hidden");
            },
        })

        var FooterImgUrl = '/Portals/' + portalNum + '/Images/footer_bg.jpg'

        $.ajax({
            url: FooterImgUrl, //or your url
            success: function (data) {
                $(".RowFooter").css("background-image", "url(" + FooterImgUrl + ")");
                $(".RowFooter").css("background-position", "center top");
                $(".RowFooter").css("background-size", "2000px auto");
                $(".RowFooter").css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
                $(".RowFooter").css("overflow", "hidden");
            },
        })

    })

</script>
```

**Two questions:**

1. How can I improve this code?
2. I want to move the CSS rules into a CSS class in the pages skin.css file.  How can I add a CSS class to the existing one that I am adding the CSS rules to?

Comment: Can you give some sample inputs? It's hard to understand the code when you don't know the input.

Comment: sure, the only inputs are the url of the website page (ie www.website.com/MyPage or www.website.com/MyPage.aspx) and the regex search for "n/portal.css" where n is an integer that I want to extract.  The css classes are hard coded in because they will never change (RowPageHeader and RowFooter).  Does this help @JosephtheDreamer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically every duplicated object can be made one object. And maybe use a function so you can call it when required.

If you use an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) like below, you can put this code in an external *.js file. It will then run asap without stalling other http requests while loading the page. Also pass in the `jQuery` object as a parameter so you can safely use `$` instead.

1. The configuration separation allows you to easily change things when needed. They're also grouped and give you a better overview. Compared to the other objects the `cfg` variable is the "local global" so you can use `cfg` throughout your whole script.
2. The window object groups your functionality or component in one object. Basically one DOM object for a project is ideal imho. Allows you to access `window.ComponentName` in other files as well.
3. The activation is under your control. For the moment it uses the common DOM ready event and basically just runs the `init()` function.

```
// @param ($): jquery version x?
(function ($) {
    // 1. CONFIGURATION
    var cfg = {
        rowpageheader: '.RowPageHeader',
        rowfooter: '.RowFooter',
        options: {
            header: {
                'background-position': 'center top',
                'background-size': '100% auto',
                'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                'overflow': 'hidden'
            },
            footer: {
                'background-position': 'center top',
                'background-size': '2000px auto',
                'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                'overflow': 'hidden'
            }
        },
        path: {
            portal: 'Portals',
            images: 'Images'
        },
        misc: {
            portalcss: 'portal.css',
            imagequality: '_hd.jpg',
            footerbg: 'footer_bg.jpg'
        }
    };

    // 2. DOM OBJECT
    window.Images = {
        init: function () {
            this.cacheItems();
            this.activate();
        },

        cacheItems: function () {
            this.rowPageHeader = $(cfg.rowpageheader);
            this.rowFooter = $(cfg.rowfooter);
        },

        activate: function () {
            var cfgOptions = cfg.options, 
                portalNum = this.getPortalNum(),
                pageName = this.getPageName();

            this.updateHeader(portalNum, pageName, cfgOptions.header);
            this.updateFooter(portalNum, cfgOptions.footer);
        },

        getPageName: function () {
            var loc = window.location.href,
                fileNameIndex = loc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                dotIndex = loc.lastIndexOf('.');

            return loc.substring(fileNameIndex, dotIndex < fileNameIndex ? loc.length : dotIndex);
        },

        getPortalNum: function () {
            var head = document.head,
                portalcss = cfg.misc.portalcss,
                regexp = '/\/[0-9]+\/' + portalcss + '/',
                portalCss = head.innerHTML.match(regexp),
                portalNum = portalCss[0].replace('/', '');

            return portalNum.replace(portalcss, '');
        },

        updateHeader: function (portalNum, pageName, options) {
            var proj = this,
                cfgPath = cfg.path,
                headerUrl = [cfgPath.portal, portalNum, cfgPath.images, pageName, cfg.misc.imagequality];

            $.ajax({
                url: headerUrl.join('/')
            }).done(function () {
                var opt = $.extend(options, { backgroundImage: 'url(' + headerUrl + ')' });
                proj.rowPageHeader.css(opt);
            });
        },

        updateFooter: function (portalNum, options) {
            var proj = this,
                cfgPath = cfg.path,
                footerUrl = [cfgPath.portal, portalNum, cfgPath.images, cfg.misc.footerbg];

            $.ajax({
                url: footerUrl.join('/')
            }).done(function () {
                var opt = $.extend(options, { backgroundImage: 'url(' + footerUrl + ')' });
                proj.rowFooter.css(opt);
            });
        }
    };

    // 3. DOM READY
    $(function () {
        $(document).foundation();
        Images.init();
    });
} (jQuery));
```

Haven't checked if this works, but it should ^^

Comment: thats a lot to process for a first time java user. thanks, learned a lot